# Filter PHP list with angularJS

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, angularjs

I am trying to create a blog page and I chose WordPress over AngularJS so Google can index the page ( or at least that's what i think it works). So for now I have a list which looks like this

```
<ul>
    <li id="1">
        <h2>My first Post</h2>
        <p>The Message...</p>
    </li>
    <li id="2">
        <h2>My second Post</h2>
        <p>The Message...</p>
    </li>
    <li id="3">
        <h2>My third Post</h2>
        <p>The Message...</p>
    </li>
</ul>
```

but PHP is pretty static so I want to create a angular filter to filter posts by title, but I don't really know how to do this.

I was thinking to create a hide class for `<li>` items and somehow if a post should be deleted because of the filter, to add the hide class to it. I  try to mix this angular so I can have a dynamic search instad loading the page again after searching.

Comment: It seems you already have the `li` and now you want to filter the results. Is that right?

Comment: yes, i have the li's and i could also generate a json with id and title, id to detect which li to hide and title for filtering iwth angular, but i have to idea when i filter the list how to hide the li's that are filtered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a directive to wrap the html content you receive from php, pass the filter term and which element of the list you want to check).

Here is a plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/Bv2opi5CHfJa0pQyFrBc?p=preview

(this require jquery to hide and show, but you can use css({'display':'none|block'}) too)

(maybe you could modify the directive to apply the filter term to ignore the case of the words)

**app.js**

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.model = {
        filter: ''
    };
});

app.directive('myHtmlFilter', [function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
          filter: '=myHtmlFilter',
          element: '@'
        },
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
          scope.$watch('filter', function(newval, oldval) {
            elem
              .find('ul>li')
                  .hide()
                  .find(scope.element)
                  .filter(':contains("'+scope.filter+'")')
               .parent()
                  .show();
          })
        }
    }
}]);
```

**index.html**

```
<input type="text" ng-model="model.filter" />

<div my-html-filter="model.filter" element="h2">
  <ul>
    <li id="1">
        <h2>My first Post</h2>
        <p>The Message...</p>
    </li>
    <li id="2">
        <h2>My second Post</h2>
        <p>The Message...</p>
    </li>
    <li id="3">
        <h2>My third Post</h2>
        <p>The Message...</p>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**Edit** I updated the plunker with a more complete example than the code shown here.

Comment: this is just GREAT ! thank you so much for this "too advanced for me" technique" :D i will google and try to understand how this works, thank you again!

Comment: Let me know if you have any question about this code! Try to look for the directives docs if you are not familiar with them, it is the biggest feature of angular IMO.

Answer (score 3):

Considering you don't have a service that will return only the JSON formatted items, the best approach would be creating a directive that remove the `li`, parse their contents to an object and use `ng-repeat` in a template. Something like this:

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.directive('filtered', function() {
  return {
    scope: {
      criteria: '=filtered'
    },
    compile: function(elm, attr) {
      var entries = [];

      elm.find('li').each(function(index, item) {
        var entry;

        $item = angular.element(item);

        entries.push({
              id: $item.attr('id'),
          title: $item.find('h2').text(),
          body: $item.find('p').text()
        });
      }).remove();

      elm.append(
        '<li ng-repeat="entry in entries | filter:{title: criteria}" id={{entry.id}}>' +
          '<h2>{{entry.title}}</h2>' +
          '<p>{{entry.body}}</p>' +
        '</li>'
      );

      return function(scope) {
        scope.entries = entries;
      };
    }
  };
});
```

And in your HTML you just decorate the list with the directive:

```html
<input ng-model="userCriteria">

<ul filtered="userCriteria">
  <li id="1">
    <h2>My first Post</h2>
    <p>The Message...</p>
  </li>
  <li id="2">
    <h2>My second Post</h2>
    <p>The Message 2...</p>
  </li>
  <li id="3">
    <h2>My third Post</h2>
    <p>The Message 3...</p>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I've put together a [Plnkr here](http://plnkr.co/edit/xFgttt?p=preview). Go ahead and change the HTML list and it will automatically include that items.

Comment: thank you very much for this answer this is a little more complecated for me but it works great!

Answer (score 0):

If you can have the JSON approach, then Angular automatically does that for you.

Just go with a simple filter solution:

```html
<input ng-model="criteria"/>

<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="entry in entries | filter:{title: criteria}" id="{{entry.id}}">
    <h2>{{entry.title}}</h2>
    <p>{{entry.body}}</p>
  </li>
</ul>
```

In your controller (or any JS with access to the container scope):

```js
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.criteria = "Title";

  $scope.entries = [
    {
      id: 1,
      title: 'My title',
      body: 'contents...'
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      title: 'The other content',
      body: 'contents...'
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      title: 'Another title',
      body: 'contents...'
    },
    {
      id: 4,
      title: 'Something completely different',
      body: 'contents...'
    }
  ];
});
```

You can even use [`$http`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24http) service to retrieve the JSON file:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.criteria = "Title";
  $scope.entries = $http.get('path/to/entries.json');
});
```

Comment: This is what i am trying to avoid. I have the list generated by php already but i want to use AngularJS only to hide / show the li items that are filtered by an angular filter.